# Should I install plotly.js or plotly.js-dist via npm?

Tags: javascript, npm, plotly, libraries, plotly.js

There are two packages **plotly.js** and **plotly.js-dist**.

What is the difference between them and which one should I use?

Moreover on npmjs.org on **plotly.js** page it says in order to install **plotly.js** one have to run:

```
npm install plotly.js-dist
```

I mean, I can see that **plotly.js** is a project with many files, and that **plotly.js-dist** is a bundle, just one file. But I don't get why it is distributed like this.

Especially, that **plotly.js-dist** is not minified, and in **plotly.js** there is minified file, which I guess can be used in order to import this library to one's project.

Answer (score 4):

These files are same. I checked and compared.

If you using npm + typescript(+Angular), I recommend to use option , `npm install plotly.js-dist`.
If you using npm(or not) + javascript, I recommend to use option 3 with `plotly.min.js`.

Don't mention minified or not. Because after bundling every module minified.
So, it's up to you which file need to see via developer tool while debugging.

Here is [Quick start options](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js).

1. Install with npm : `npm install plotly.js-dist`.

- Ready-to-use plotly.js distributed bundle.
- Contains trace modules, visit [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/plotly.js-dist)

2. Use the plotly.js CDN hosted by Fastly.
3. Download the latest release : `plotly.js` or `plotly.min.js`. More info [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/dist/README.md).

It doesn't matter what you choose but it is different slightly how to bundle/deploy your project.
And using definition file. [@types/plotly.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/plotly.js)
For further information from here, check [Bundle information](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/dist/README.md) section.

Also, if you work with angular? here is another option :  [angular-plotly.js](https://github.com/plotly/angular-plotly.js).

---

This is my answer for your second phrase.
"plotly.js" is hard to set it up for bundling.
Here is what I've done with this and my goal was:

1. Working on angular2-seed with Angular 4.
2. Fully defined each type/interface.

##### Step 1. Install package.

Change command, thanks @Jesse

```bash
npm install plotly.js-dist --save
npm install @types/plotly.js --save-dev
npm install @types/d3 --save-dev
```

*Note: @types/d3 is dependency of @types/plotly.js. but if you don't need it, remove it from index.d.ts.*

##### Step 2. rename folder to use definition file.

Rename folder "plotly.js" to "plotly.js-dist" in "node_modules/@types".

##### Update - 9/12/2023

This is my env;

- windows 11(x64)
- Node v18.17.1
- Angular 13.2.0

I recommend as below,

```bash
npm i --save plotly.js-dist-min
npm i --save-dev @types/plotly.js-dist-min
```

This is little bit different between official guide.

```js
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Plotly from 'plotly.js-dist-min';

@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {  
  myData!: Partial<Plotly.PlotData>[];
  @ViewChild('chart') div?: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myData = [
      {
        x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
        y: [20, 14, 23],
        type: 'bar',
      },
    ];
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const element = this.div?.nativeElement;
    Plotly.newPlot(element, this.myData);
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll want to install your types as a devDependency with `--save-dev` or `-D`. NOT in dependencies with `--save`. Also renaming folders in node_modules is a bad idea, unless you're sure it's a local, personal project. It's just very easy to end with a package that's out of sync across devices.

Comment: How do you do this if you are using Yarn PNP setup?

Comment: Sorry @Zaffer, I don't have much experience with Yarn PNP, so I can't provide you with additional information.